# Memory leak in function, that return pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

Does this code have a potential memory leak problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> foo()
{
    vector<int> vec2;
    vec2.push_back(0);

    return vec2;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec1;

    while(true)
    {
        vec1 = foo();   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There is no problem if I use a function that returns a number, like `int`, because we copy value from memory stack. But if I use `pointer` (and I think the compiler does not copy arrays, vectors and other large data structures - it implicitly works with pointers), the situation changes.

In `foo` I allocate memory for vector and create pointer to it `vec2`. Then, I create second pointer to this memory sector `vec1` and immediately delete pointer `vec2` because function `foo` was ended.

On the second iteration of the `while`, I allocate a new sector of memory in `foo` and change pointer `vec1` to this area.

So, what happened with that first allocate sector? I didn't make it free on any step. But I don't see any leak when I watch memory the used by the process.

Comment: "and if I know, compiler does not copy arrays, vectors and other large data structures - it implicitly works with pointers" - well, you've got that wrong. Perhaps you've read stuff about Java and mixed it up with C++.

Comment: Is `foo` a vector or a function?  This does not compile as c++ code using the g++ compiler

Comment: @masfo001 a set of parentheses are missing after the declaration of `foo`

Comment: I don't see any memory leaks in your code.  I tested using [valgrind](https://github.com/mikeizbicki/ucr-cs100/tree/2015spring/textbook/tools/valgrind) . Just edit the `while` loop so that it's not infinite.

Answer (score 4):

There are no memory leaks because:

- The `std::vector<T>` has value type semantics:

  > Destructs the container. The destructors of the elements are called and the used storage is deallocated. Note, that if the elements are pointers, the pointed-to objects are not destroyed.
  >
  > -- [std::vector::~vector, C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/~vector).
- The `std::vector<T>` is used with value type (`int` in the described case) as type parameter.
- All used `std::vector<T>` instances (variables) are **automatic**.

  > In C++, the constructor of automatic variables is called when the execution reaches the place of declaration. The destructor is called when it reaches the end of the given program block (program blocks are surrounded by curly brackets). This feature is often used to **manage resource allocation and deallocation**, like opening and then automatically closing files or **freeing up memory**. See RAII.
  >
  > -- [Automatic variable: C, C++, Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable).

Back to the question:

> In foo I allocate memory for vector and create pointer to it (vec2). Then, I create second pointer to this memory sector (vec1) and immediately delete pointer vec2 because function foo was ended. On second iteration in while I allocate new sector of memory in foo and change pointer vec1 to this area.
>
> So, what happened with that first allocate sector? I didn't make it free on any step.

First of all, there are no pointers in the posted source code. The "low level" memory management is encapsulated into `std::vector<T>`. Please see the references to find the details:

- [Resource Acquisition Is Initialization, Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).
- [Copy constructor, Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor) and [Return value optimization (RVO), Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).
- Copy constructor `vector( const vector& other ); (5)` ([std::vector::vector, C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)).
- Assignment operator `vector& operator=( const vector& other ); (1)` ([std::vector::operator=, C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D)).